# Azure Function deploy error: Your function app is targeting V1, but Azure host has function version V2,

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'am trying to deploy my new created function with .net core
This is my project content and my function on azure is configured with version 2 and the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION is ~2.

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

If I do a deploy over my local repository it throws me this error.

```
remote: Your function app is targeting V1, but Azure host has function version V2,
remote: please change the version using the portal or update your 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION' appsetting and retry
```

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: How do you deploy your function and have you tried to run it locally?

Comment: function runs fine locally and I deploy the function over a local git repo with a simple git push

Comment: Just tried and no error shows. What's your `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package version? It's 1.0.* on my side, which indicates the latest.

Comment: Can you please check the files in Azure (e.g. with Kudu) that all is deployed correct. Does your host.json have "version": "2.0" inside? And please ensure that these files have a "copy always" in the build action.

Comment: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions is 1.0.24

Comment: no files deployed to wwwroot only the host file is there. inside my hostfile locally and on the server a have {
  "version": "2.0"
}

Comment: In the deployed app, can you make sure that your app is targeted to the correct runtime version? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version)

Comment: the target framework of my function is .net core 2.1. If I understand right the documentation that should be a valid version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had was a unloaded unit test .net 4.7 project. After removing that I am able to publish to azure.